# Opposite of “extra dressing“?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I want my salad to have more dressing, I’ll order it with *extra dressing*. Is there an adjective that would mean less-than-normal in this context?

Comment: What is “*I’ll order it with less dressing”* not okay? It’s a request at the end of the day.

Comment: “Dressing on the side, please” is typical in the US.

Comment: @Xanne That means no dressing on the salad, though. Not less.

Comment: @AlecAlameddine - That means you can add as much as you want.

Comment: I know, but it’s still a different ask

Comment: “Easy on the dressing” may work. Then again, it may not. Those who take your order may have limited knowledge of English.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, you'd use the word "light".

For example:  I'll have ham on rye, light on the mustard.

This is the general terminology used for ordering food.

From [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/light#etymonline_v_9503)

light (adj.1)
"not heavy, having little actual weight," from Old English leoht (West Saxon), leht (Anglian), "not heavy, light in weight; lightly constructed; easy to do, trifling; quick, agile," also of food, sleep, etc., from Proto-Germanic *lingkhtaz (source also of Old Norse lettr, Swedish lätt, Old Frisian, Middle Dutch licht, German leicht, Gothic leihts), from PIE root *legwh- "not heavy, having little weight." The adverb is Old English leohte, from the adjective.

Below is an image from Panera's app with the options for salad dressing.

[image]

Comment: I feel like "light on the mustard" is an idiom. Not all waiters will understand, so maybe it is better to be more direct. Also when people describe *light* food they are not referring necessarily to the quantity, but whether it is *light* or *heavy* on their stomach.

Comment: Aesking - 40 years of ordering food that way argues against that. See my revision with picture.

Comment: ...maybe 40 years in the US...light, regular and extra aren't common options when referring to food quantities in the UK.

Comment: Light might also refer to the type of dressing rather than the quantity thereof. A lighter dressing might be mostly oil and vinegar whereas a regular dressing might have some yoghurt to thicken it.

Comment: @JJJ *Light on the dressing* would rarely be misconstrued as a request for *light dressing*.

Comment: Hello! Long time no see. It's been ages, how ya doin'? I hope well. Welcome back!

Comment: I only pop on once in a blue moon ...

Answer (score 0):

*Reduced* is a reasonable opposite to *extra* in this context - both words indicate a variation from some standard quantity.

*Reduced* is commonly used in the names of food products available at the supermarket: any number of things have a "reduced salt" (or "salt reduced") variation, or "reduced fat" or "reduced sugar ".

Of course I can't guarantee that staff at any given restaurant will interpret "salad with reduced dressing" the way you intend - both *reduced* and *extra* are somewhat subjective measurements, so you're probably better off ordering the dressing on the side.